# Use Python to remotely connect to a k8s pod and send commands on that pod

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a scenario where if I want to run a postgres query or check a kafka topic my only option is to connect to a pod that has those privileges and from there either run the relevant kafka command or in the case of a db query I need to connect and then run the query.

Is there a 'somewhat' elegant way of wrapping these fairly simple commands in a python app?  It would be something akin to pipeing several commands but I'm not sure of how to make this work as so far attempts have failed.

My use cases are similar to:

- kubectl exec -it pod bash
- run kafka command

or

- kubectl exec -it pod bash - same pod as above
- connect to postgres db
- run query

Thanks in advance for any help, a pointer in the right direction would be fantastic as relatively new to python.

Comment: Does anything stop you from running the program directly in the cluster, and just connecting to the database or queueing system directly?  I'd generally reserve `kubectl exec` for debugging tasks; in this context consider that it requires credentials and specific permissions to be usable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Brainstorming Idea:** You can wrap commands in one Python file and run it on the K8s master node:

```
import subprocess

def run_kafka_command(pod_name, kafka_command):
    command = f'kubectl exec -it {pod_name} -- bash -c "{kafka_command}"'
    result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    return result.stdout

def run_postgres_query(pod_name, database, query):
    command = f'kubectl exec -it {pod_name} -- psql -d {database} -c "{query}"'
    result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    return result.stdout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pod_name = "your_pod_name"
    kafka_command = "your_kafka_command"
    database = "your_database"
    query = "your_query"

    kafka_output = run_kafka_command(pod_name, kafka_command)
    print("Kafka Command Output:")
    print(kafka_output)

    postgres_output = run_postgres_query(pod_name, database, query)
    print("Postgres Query Output:")
    print(postgres_output)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with that and see if I can then expans on it to have a basic UI or at least a 'run command 1 as an option type thing

Comment: if u like the idea, if u accept the answer, I’ll be pleased, thanks..